# How to create generic viewmodelfactory without using dagger?

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel, dagger-2

Is there a way to create a single/generic viewmodelfactory class without using Dagger?

I've researched around and it seems like everyone is content with using dagger to create VMF but what is you are using a different DI framework like [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/)?

This is the standard Dagger implementation:

```
class ViewModelProviderFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Can this be done another way, without using the `Provider` and `Inject` from dagger?

Comment: Can you specify for what purpose you want to create the factory? Are you using Koin? If so, I believe [Koin can handle ViewModel injection without custom factory](https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/getting-started/android-viewmodel/).